# About 'on a dare', 'dare' in passive and 'daren't'

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, verbs, phrase-meaning, phrases

> - She learned to fly on a dare. (oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com)

1. Does this mean she was dared by someone to fly? Was she challenged
   by someone?
2. Is it ok to use 'dare' in passive voice like I did here?
3. Is the shortened form, 'daren't,' commonly used?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hard to say for sure. Maybe she was [double-dog dared](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIR759wIjdg) :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To do something *on a dare* means exactly what you suspect: to do something in response to a challenge.
2. Yes, *dare* may be cast in the passive voice, just as you used it.
3. *Daren't* is pretty rare in US speech these days; we generally say *don't/doesn't/didn't dare*.

Comment: (3) ... or sometimes *dare not*, *dares not*.

Comment: I think there's still a pretty strictly observed US/UK difference here. There aren't actually enough instances to *directly* compare US/UK charts for [*did it **on** a dare, did it **for** a dare*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+it+on+a+dare%2Cdid+it+for+a+dare&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdid%20it%20on%20a%20dare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdid%20it%20for%20a%20dare%3B%2Cc0), but the second of those (which is the UK standard version) disappears completely if you switch to the US-only corpus.